# I want to perform 2000 transactions but when i am looping trough the eosjs code it throws an error

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions, eosjs, eosio.token

The error name is expired_tx_exception and the code for the same is 3040005 please tell me how can I perform these much transactions per seconds. 
I am able to perform 250 transactions per seconds but after that, it is throwing this error.

The code is as follows:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    contract
            .transfer(
              {
                from: "myaccount",
                to: "myaccount2",
                quantity: "1.0000 SYS",
                memo: i
              },
              {
                authorization: ["myaccount@active"]
              }
            )
            .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
              fs.appendFileSync("test.json", JSON.stringify(res));
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

Comment: First of all, use Promise.all not loop.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your problem can be in the node configuration, not in your code. try this: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3370

also you code is kind of slow because you run all actions in a sequence, not in parallel. so if you will not reach desired speed after fixing your error - try to remove bottlenecks like - remove logs - they take time and try to run a few instances of you script in parallel (redirect logs in different files if you really need it). node js is single threaded, so running a few instances can make total throughput way bigger (of cause if you have multiple-core CPU).